# ASP.NET Configure update button in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

I am using C# ASP.NET on VS2005.

I have a gridview table but it does not have a selection for *Enable Editing* when I right click on the *Smart Tab*.

Thus I manually added the edit button with the following code:

`AutoGenerateEditButton="True"`

The edit button has successfully appeared on my gridview like this:
[image]

When I click on the *Edit* button, the page is refreshed and the row is now editable:
[image]

However, when I pressed on the update button, I was brought to the error:

`Updating is not supported by data source 'SqlDataSource1' unless UpdateCommand is specified.`

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W97K0.png

I have no clue on how I can input or configure the `UpdateCommand` because I don't see any background code for the `Update` button.

Need help from experienced. Thank you in advance.

---

Edited: Added INSERT query in `SqlDataSource1`, however I still met the same error when I press the `Update` button.

Comment: As you asked for example in your comment, please have a look..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to re-configure the `SqlDataSource1` control though which you can add support for `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE` along with `SELECT`.

Take a look at [this](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/inserting-updating-and-deleting-data-with-the-sqldatasource-vb) tutorial.

Comment: Thanks, I will configure now. But can I have an example on how my INSERT statement will be? I am not sure how do I bind the INSERT statement with that specific editable row. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

while configurting sqldatasource when you configure the select statement for the gridview,there is a option as "advanced".click on that and then click on 'generate update,insert nad delete statements".

Answer (score 0):

For example, try this out...

1. Firstly create a method to handle the update record.

   ```
   private void UpdateOrAddNewRecord(string parametervalue1, string parametervalue2)
       {
           using (openconn())
           {
               string sqlStatement = string.Empty;
               sqlStatement = "Update TableName set Name1 =@Name1 where Name2@Name2";


               try
               {
               //  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("storedprocedureName", con);
                 //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, con);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name2", parametervalue2);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name1",parametervalue1);

                   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

               }


               catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
               {

                   string msg = "Insert/Update Error:";

                   msg += ex.Message;

                   throw new Exception(msg);


               }

               finally
               {

                   closeconn();

               }
           }
   ```
2. Now create the row updating method..

   ```
   protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
       {
           string ParameterValue1 = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Controls[0]).Text;

           string ParameterValue2 = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text; //Name

           UpdateOrAddNewRecord(ParameterValue1, ParameterValue2); // call update method

           GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
           BindGridView();
           Label2.Visible = true;
           Label2.Text = "Row Updated";
       }
   ```
3. Create Row Cancelling event..

   protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
       {
           GridView1.EditIndex = -1; //swicth back to default mode
           BindGridView();
       }
4. Create row editing...

   protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
       {
           GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
           BindGridView();
       }

There are so many other way out to do this same activity in different fashion. This is most elementary way. Anyways if you find it useful, please mark it as your answer else let me know...

Answer (score 0):

```
In your code I think you have not handled the event for "Update".


Have a look at the below example hope it might help you,
check for the "UpdateCommand".
Also write a Update event in C# to update.



<asp:DetailsView ID="ManageProducts" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"
    AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="ProductID"
    DataSourceID="ManageProductsDataSource" EnableViewState="False">
    <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID"
            InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ProductID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="ProductName"
            SortExpression="ProductName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitPrice" HeaderText="UnitPrice"
            SortExpression="UnitPrice" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Discontinued" HeaderText="Discontinued"
            SortExpression="Discontinued" />
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ManageProductsDataSource" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NORTHWNDConnectionString %>"
    DeleteCommand=
        "DELETE FROM [Products] WHERE [ProductID] = @ProductID"
    InsertCommand=
        "INSERT INTO [Products] ([ProductName], [UnitPrice], [Discontinued])
         VALUES (@ProductName, @UnitPrice, @Discontinued)"
    SelectCommand=
        "SELECT [ProductID], [ProductName], [UnitPrice], [Discontinued]
         FROM [Products]"
    UpdateCommand=
        "UPDATE [Products] SET [ProductName] = @ProductName,
         [UnitPrice] = @UnitPrice, [Discontinued] = @Discontinued
         WHERE [ProductID] = @ProductID">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ProductID" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ProductName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="UnitPrice" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Discontinued" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ProductID" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ProductName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="UnitPrice" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Discontinued" Type="Boolean" />
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```