# Add button to right end of Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with AutoGenerateColumns set to FALSE. I have manually added the columns (BoundField and ButtonField) to make sure the button displays at the last column since the default position of ButtonField added is on the first column if AutoGenerateColumns is set to TRUE.

And with AutoGenerateColumns set to TRUE, the below code works fine. However, if I change it to false and add the BoundFields and ButtonField, it doesn't work. The query works fine and I have seen the Gridview getting populated without issues if AutoGenerateColumns is set to TRUE.

Please assist how to fix it. I want the Button to the right side of the column. Hence the below aspx design.

**Code:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" Width="100%" EmptyDataText="No records to display." AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="COL1" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="COL2" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="COL3" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="COL4" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="COL5" />
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" Text="Update"/>
    </Columns>
    ........
 </asp:GridView>


DataTable GetData()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string LoginDbCS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UserDetails"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(LoginDbCS);
    SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand("SELECT [COL1], [COL2], [COL3], [COL4], [COL5] FROM dbo.tableUser WHERE @User = Username", Conn);

    try
    {
        Conn.Open();
        Command.Parameters.Add("User", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Username;

        SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(Command);
        adpt.Fill(dt);
        Conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception Er)
    {
        ....
        if (Conn != null)
            Conn.Dispose();
        }
        ....
    }
    return dt;
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ....
    GridView1.DataSource = GetData();
    GridView1.DataBind();
    ....
}
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264670/asp-net-configure-update-button-in-gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" Width="100%" EmptyDataText="No records to display." AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="COL1" HeaderText="COL1" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="COL2" HeaderText="COL2" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="COL3" HeaderText="COL3" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="COL4" HeaderText="COL4" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="COL5" HeaderText="COL5" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" SelectText="Update"/>
    </Columns>
    ........
 </asp:GridView>
```

and then create an event for SelectedIndexChanged to handle the selected row